# Proving $(X,Y)$ is a normal vector when $X\sim N(1,1)$ and $Y\mid X\sim N(3X,4)$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, conditional-probability, bivariate-distributions

Suppose I have a random vector $(X,Y)$ with $X\sim\mathcal{N}(1,1)$ and $Y|X = x \sim\mathcal{N}(3x,4)$.

I need to prove that $(X,Y)$ is a normal vector as well.

To do that I want to explicitly write the vector of expected values and the $2x2$ matrix of variance and covariance.

I know that the first entry of the vector of expected values is 1 and the entry $C_{1,1}$ of the matrix is 1 as well. However I am struggling to see how I can derive the density function of Y from the conditional one.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Joint density of $(X,Y)$ is $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_{Y\mid X}(y)f_X(x)=...$

Comment: Yes, but I am trying to calculate E[Y], V[Y] and Cov[X,Y] to "fill" the matrices. I am struggling with Cov[X,Y], specifically with E[XY]. Do you have an hint for that?

Comment: Comment made by @StubbornAtom below his/her answer needs to be emphasized. Just finding the mean vector and the variance-covariance matrix do not show the joint-normality of $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could say $Y=3X+Z$ where $Z\sim N(0,4)$ independent of $X$.

It is then an easy step to say that $Y\sim N(3\times 1+0,3^2\times 1+4)$  and

- $E[X]=1$
- $E[Y]=3$
- $\text{Var}(X)=1$
- $\text{Var}(Y)=13$
- $\text{Cov}(X,Y)=\text{Cov}(X,3X)=3\text{Var}(X)=3$

Comment: This is the direction I took as well. However I did not use an additional Z. Therefore I am struggling with calculating the covariance between X and Y, could you take a look at my comment to the answer below?

Answer (score 2):

You can proceed with moment generating functions.

Joint MGF of $(X,Y)$ is

\begin{align}
M(s,t)&=E\left[e^{sX+tY}\right]
\\&=E\left[E(e^{sX+tY}\mid X)\right]
\\&=E\left[e^{sX}E(e^{tY}\mid X)\right]
\end{align}

From the given information, you should be able to show that this MGF corresponds to the MGF of a bivariate normal distribution. That would complete your proof using the uniqueness property of MGF.

Comment: I am not sure I am following you. In my problem I did find Variance and Expected value of Y, using the tower property of conditioning. I stil need to find the two symmetric entries of the matrix of variance and covariance to complete what I want to do. That is I need to find Covariance[X,Y]. Calculating, I get to this: $$Cov[X,Y] = E[XY] - 3E[X^2] -E[Y] + 3E[X]$$ Above, I know everything except E[XY]. I did the following: $ E[XY] = E[ E[XY|X]] = E[YE[X|X]] = E[Y E[X]]$ but I get the wrong result ( covariance should be 3 but I get -3). Could you point out what I did wrong?

Comment: @qcc101 $E(XY)=E(E(XY\mid X))=E(XE(Y\mid X))=...$

Comment: Right, silly mistake. I will investigate the part about moment generating functions as well. Thank you.

Comment: @qcc101 Without the argument that $X$ and $Y$ are linear combinations of independent normal variables and hence $(X,Y)$ is bivariate normal (as seen in the answer by @Henry), I don't think finding the variance-covariance matrix (only) as you are trying to do is sufficient for the given question.